# How to add Tailwind in Laravel Mix

Tags: laravel

I want to use autocomplete in Laravel Mix. The tutorial I saw was using vue-cli and it's working. It is using tailwind, but when I implement it in Laravel Mix using `npm install`, it does not work. I used a tutorial to install Tailwind in Laravel Mix but I can not find tailwind.js under resources/js. If I want to write a manual how I write those file link tutorial below.

https://sandulat.com/blog/installing-tailwind-into-laravel/

Comment: Have you done step 4 in that tutorial link?

Answer (score 4):

Tailwind.js will not be generated in resources/js. When you run

```
npx tailwind init
```

or

```
./node_modules/.bin/tailwind init
```

the tailwind.js will be placed in the directory your terminal is currently in. Your webpack.mix.js would look something like this:

```
const mix = require('laravel-mix');

const tailwindcss = require('tailwindcss');

mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
    .sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css')
    .options({
        processCssUrls: false,
        postCss: [tailwindcss('./tailwind.js')],
    });
```

Note the processCssUrls: false, this IS required for mix to compile tailwind.

You could also install a simple npm package:
[Laravel Mix Tailwind](https://github.com/JeffreyWay/laravel-mix-tailwind)